# Implementation of List Inside List

Tags: android, nested-lists

I've been trying to look for the right answer, but couldn't find something clear.

I have a list of items, using custom ArrayAdapter.
Now each Item has click listener. 
I want to add another list, so when someone clicks on one of the times, another list will pop up.

Now how should I implement the second list? should I combine it somehow in the current ArrayAdapter and it's wrapping Activity? Should I create a separate Custom adapter and activity for the second list?

I have also seen something about ViewSwitcher, is that the answer to this question?

Any ideas?

Thanks,
ray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at ExpandableList?

```
YourAdapter implements ExpandableListAdapter
```

I think this might be the behaviour you are looking for.

Comment: I ran with your idea, but I got question in that subject, mybe you could answer it-> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366132/delete-group-in-expandable-list