# Delete group in Expandable List

Tags: android, android-expandable-list-view

I am trying to delete Group when selected in my **Expandable List** and having the list refreshed after the delete occurred.

I took the source code from google:

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ExpandableList1.html

I tried a couple of ways to delete it, but no success, anyone achieved that already?

Thanks,
ray.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer for the second question (Add rows to a child & datastructure)

For the Datastructure:

```
public class GroupItem {
 private String mItemText;
 private List<ChildItem> mChildItems=new ArrayList<ChildItem>();    

 public GroupItem(String itemText) {
  mItemText=itemText;
 }

 public String getItemText() {
  return mItemText;
 }

 public ChildItem getChild(int childPosition) {
  return mChildItems.get(childPosition);
 }

 public void addChild(ChildItem childItem) {
  return mChildItems.add(childItem)
 }

 public void removeChild(int childPosition) {
  return mChildItems.remove(childPosition);
 }

}

public class ChildItem {
 private String mItemText;
 public ChildItem(itemText) {
  mItemText=itemText;
 }

 public String getItemText() {
  return mItemText;
 }
}
```

Now to set it up you would do something like:

```
List<GroupItem> items = new ArrayList<GroupItem>();

GroupItem item1 = new GroupItem("This is group 1");
item1.addChild(new ChildItem("This is a child item of group 1"));
item1.addChild(new ChildItem("This is another child item of group 1"));
```

and so on...

Then, in the Adapter you would need to return the appropriate data.

For your question concerning rows: 
In your Google example, they return a TextView. You can however make your own Layout with whatever content you like. For example:

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/RowIcon" 
  android:layout_width="56px" 
  android:layout_height="56px" 
  android:layout_marginLeft="12px" 
  android:layout_marginTop="2px">
</ImageView>
<TextView android:id="@+id/RowTextView"
     android:paddingLeft="10px"
     android:paddingTop="10px"       
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="#666666" android:textSize="14px"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

And then use this Layout in your Adapter. Instead of returning, say, a TextView, you'll just return this as a View:

```
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View rowView = mInflater.inflate(YOUR XML FILE FROM ABOVE, null);
    ImageView rowIcon = (ImageView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.RowIcon);
    iconType.setBackgroundResource(AN IMAGE HERE);
    TextView rowText =(TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.RowTextView);
    textAddress.setText(items.get(groupPosition).getChild(childPosition));

    return rowView;
 }
```

So, i think that should get you going.

Also, please accept my answers if they satisfy you.

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks bro, your answers are great. tell me somethong, i am trying to switch the view to another view by doing: ExpandableList.this.setContentView(R.layout.errorscreen);, and I get this exception:  ERROR/AndroidRuntime(23948): java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ExpandableListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'   Any idea why? thanks once again.

Comment: And about the layout you just wrote, where have you declared the variable "textAddress" ?

Comment: Hey. I took this from some project i worked on. textAdress ist just a variable I forgot to change. Rename to rowText :). As for the RuntimeException: Just do exactly what it sais - Add an ExpandableListView to your xml layout and set it's id to list. Like so: <ExpandableListView 
  android:id="@id/android:list"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

Comment: But I dont have any access to the ExpandableListView layout, I never made an xml, I guess it takes it by default from somewhere, how would you adjust it?

Comment: You are doing ExpandableList.this.setContentView(R.layout.errorscreen) in an Activity that extends ExpandableListActivity (I guess). Such an activity needs a Layout that contains an ExpandableListView. Now either create a new Layout which contains this element (see my comment above) or add it to your existing errorscreen.xml

Answer (score 1):

Add the functionality to your Adapter to remove an Item:

```
    public void removeGroup(int group) {
        //TODO: Remove the according group. Dont forget to remove the children aswell!
        Log.v("Adapter", "Removing group"+group);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    } 

    public void removeChild(int group, int child) {
        //TODO: Remove the according child
        Log.v("Adapter", "Removing child "+child+" in group "+group);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Make sure the new methods are accessible to you by changing:

> ExpandableListAdapter mAdapter;

to

> MyExpandableListAdapter mAdapter;

Call the methods when needed:

```
 @Override
 public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    ExpandableListContextMenuInfo info = (ExpandableListContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    String title = ((TextView) info.targetView).getText().toString();

    int type = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionType(info.packedPosition);
    if (type == ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_CHILD) {
        int groupPos = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionGroup(info.packedPosition); 
        int childPos = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionChild(info.packedPosition); 
        mAdapter.removeChild(groupPos, childPos);
        return true;
    } else if (type == ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_GROUP) {
        int groupPos = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionGroup(info.packedPosition); 
        mAdapter.removeGroup(groupPos);
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

So, hope that helps. Cheers

Comment: I tried it, but in that code I cant access them(groups,children), I can access them only inside the MyExpandableListAdapter. I want to be able to access them through the onContextItemSelected, so when the user selecting i can delete it by the item which was selected

Comment: Add a method removeItem(long id) {} to the Adapter. In onContextItemSelected you do ExpandableListContextMenuInfo info = (ExpandableListContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo(); mAdapter.remove(info.getId());

Comment: This is exactly what I tried to do, but I cant find the removeItem in the mAdapter scope.. coz it's implementing an interface, and this method is not declared there. you are exactly in the same spot as I am.  - mAdapter.removeItm cannot be resolved or is not a field, after I added that method to the adapter.

Comment: I think u are creating a anonymous class of the adapter. Create a class extanding the Expandable adapter. Then add the method as metter said, and proceed on..

Comment: Ah i see the problem. You can always cheat and change ExpandableListAdapter mAdapter; to MyExpandableListAdapter mAdapter;

Comment: Yes, but it wont change the functionally some how?

Comment: Edited my initial reply. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks man for your kind answer!! although I would like to ask you, in which data structure  you recommend me to use, which will hold the content of the items? I need something to be dynamic. and second thing: if I want another row in each child, how would you do that?