# How to remove a group from an ExpandableListView Widget?

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm using a SimpleCursorTreeAdapter to fill an ExpandableListView widget. I start by providing the Adapter with a Cursor object that contains the info on the group nodes in the listview, and I define a method in the Adapter (getChildrenCursor()) to return a Cursor containing the info on the children for a specified group node.

Everything works fine, but I want to know how can I programmatically remove a group (and its children) from the ExpandableListView widget? I want to do a long-click on the group item in the list, have a popup context menu appear, and give the user the option of deleting the selected group item. I've got the context menu working ok with the long-click event, but I can't figure out how to remove a group from the list.

Can anyone offer some advice?

Thanks.

Comment: You could refer to [this SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366132/delete-group-in-expandable-list)

Comment: I did originally look at that particular response, but wasn't sure how to apply that coding to my Adapter which queries a SQLite database with a Cursor object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the user clicks the context menu entry for deleting the group you have to remove the entries in the database which match this group. After this you do a new query on the database and pass the new cursor to the adapter. Now you list should be updated and the deletes group should be gone.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So it sounds like I will need to reload the original Cursor again just to remove a single group item? That seems pretty inefficient, as the current collapse/expand status of the other displayed groups would be lost. Is there a way to remove the single item in group Cursor and do a refresh of these group items in the ExpandableListView widget?

Comment: Ok, I think I got it working. Following your suggestion, I did the following: (1) Deleted the desired records from my SQLite database table. (2) Reloaded a new cursor containing the group node information for the listview. (3) used the setGroupCursor() method on the adapter for the listview to set it to the new cursor loaded in step (1). (3) Finally, did called the notifyDataSetChanged() method on the listview adapter to refresh the list. This all worked fine, and the nodes (groups) in the list that were expanded/collapsed maintained their original condition. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Great! Yes it might sound a little bit weird at the first moment, but as you get the data from you model in your case the database you have to delete the corresponding items there to update the list. Mark my answer as accepted if it solved your problem.