# How to remove item from ExpandableList at user's will

Tags: android, expandablelistview

How do I remove an item from an `expandablelistview` at users will?

The Idea is having a little cross at the right of the item, when you click it the item vanishes. Like a `defaultexitonclose` for every Item.

I am not quite sure what to goal for is there such a thing as that?

As this was apparently not clear: My problem is NOT how to remove the item from the List, but how to get an "X" for the user to click INTO the textview!

Comment: remove item from the list and call invalidate method. It redraws the view and problem solves

Comment: Ahm the problem is HOW to place an "X" for the user to click on the item. The Problem is not removing the item but making it clickable for the user.

Comment: Try this link

[Delete group in Expandable List][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366132/delete-group-in-expandable-list

Comment: Trying at the moment - I take it this is not custom behaviour?

Comment: Well apparently it is NOT possible to inflate a button so this is no solution either.

Comment: Have a custom View with Textview and Button. Have a action to the button. which is ur "X"

Comment: I am talking about Lists. For this I would need two objects (button, textview) in ONE row inside a listview - I am not sure that is even possible.