# android expandlistview delete items

Tags: android, items

### Question description:

When I click the group ,it expand and show the childView, then click the 'delete' button in childView , it pops up an AlertDialog and after click the 'confirm' button ,the current item will be removed from the list,but My current code can not achieve this effect. Anyone has any ideas?

### here is my code:

```
public class ManageFragment extends FragmentBase{

private ExpandableListView mExpandableListView;
private ExpandListAdapter mAdapter;
private List<String> mGroups;
private HashMap<String, List<String>> mChilds;
private Button openBtn;
private TextView download_history;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_manage, container, false);
    prepareData();
    init(view);
    return view;
}
private void init(View view) {
    mAdapter = new ExpandListAdapter(getActivity(), mGroups, mChilds);
    mExpandableListView = (ExpandableListView) view.findViewById(R.id.expand_listview);
    download_history = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.download_history);

    int number = mGroups.size();
    download_history.setText(String.valueOf(number));


    mExpandableListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


    mExpandableListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
            for(int i = 0; i < mAdapter.getGroupCount(); i++){
                if(groupPosition != i){
                    mExpandableListView.collapseGroup(i);
                }
            }

        }
    });



@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}

private void prepareData() {
    mGroups = new ArrayList<String>();
    mChilds = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    mGroups.add("Group 1");
    mGroups.add("Group 2");
    mGroups.add("Group 2");
    mGroups.add("Group 2");
    mGroups.add("Group 2");
    mGroups.add("Group 2");
    mGroups.add("Group 2");

    List<String> menu = new ArrayList<String>();
    menu.add("menu 1"); 

    mChilds.put(mGroups.get(0), menu);
    mChilds.put(mGroups.get(1), menu);
}

}
```

---

```
 public class ExpandListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter implements OnClickListener{

private Context mContext;
private List<String> mGroups;
private HashMap<String, List<String>> mChilds;
private boolean flag = true;    
private TextView delete_local,delete_confirm,delete_cancel;
AlertDialog dialog;

public ExpandListAdapter(Context context, List<String> groups,
        HashMap<String, List<String>> childs) {
    mContext = context;
    mGroups = groups;
    mChilds = childs;
}

/**
 * get size list group
 */
@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return mGroups.size();
}

/**
 * get size current list child
 */
@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return mChilds.get(mGroups.get(groupPosition)).size();
}

/**
 * get object group
 */
@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return mGroups.get(groupPosition);
}

/**
 * get object child
 */
@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return mChilds.get(mGroups.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
}

/**
 * get current group id
 */
@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

/**
 * get current child id
 */
@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    //String groupText = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_layout, null);
        holder.expand_imgView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.expand_list_image);
        holder.rank_download = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rank_download);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.rank_download.setOnClickListener(this);

    if(isExpanded){
        holder.expand_imgView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.manage_collapse);
    }else{
        holder.expand_imgView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.manage_expand);
    }

    return convertView;
}

class ViewHolder{
    ImageView expand_imgView;
    Button manage_share,manage_redownload,manage_delete,rank_download;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    //String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_layout, null);

        holder.manage_share = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.manage_share);
        holder.manage_redownload = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.manage_redownload);
        holder.manage_delete = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.manage_clean);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.manage_share.setOnClickListener(this);
    holder.manage_redownload.setOnClickListener(this);
    holder.manage_delete.setOnClickListener(this);
    holder.manage_delete.setTag(groupPosition);


    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int id = v.getId();
    switch (id) {
    case R.id.manage_share:
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "share", 3).show();
        break;

    case R.id.manage_redownload:
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "redownload", 3).show();
        break;

    case R.id.manage_clean:
        showDeleteDialog();
        break;

    case R.id.rank_download:
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "open", 3).show();
        break;

    case R.id.delete_local:
        if (flag == false) {
            delete_local.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(          
                    R.drawable.checkbox_pressed, 0, 0, 0);  
            flag = true;
        }else if(flag==true){
            delete_local.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.checkbox,0,0, 0);
            flag=false;
        }
        break;

    case R.id.delete_confirm:
        Object tag = v.getTag();
        System.out.println("tag------------>" + tag);
        if(null != tag){
            mGroups.remove((Integer)tag);
            mChilds.remove((Integer)tag);
            dialog.dismiss();
            this.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }else{
            dialog.dismiss();

        }
        break;
    case R.id.delete_cancel:
        dialog.dismiss();
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}

private void showDeleteDialog() {
    dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext).create();
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.dialog_delete, null);
    delete_local = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.delete_local);
    delete_confirm = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.delete_confirm);
    delete_cancel = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.delete_cancel);
    delete_local.setOnClickListener(this);
    delete_confirm.setOnClickListener(this);
    delete_cancel.setOnClickListener(this);

    view.setMinimumWidth((int) (((Activity) mContext).getWindowManager()  
            .getDefaultDisplay().getWidth() * 0.8));
    dialog.setView(view);
    dialog.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);

    dialog.show();
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is here

```
 case R.id.delete_confirm:
    Object tag = v.getTag();
```

You're not setting a tag to delete_confirm anywhere in this code. You're setting it to manage_delete. So I would pass the the position into your showDeleteDialog method like so

```
 case R.id.manage_clean:
    int pos = (int)v.getTag();
    showDeleteDialog(pos);
    break;
```

And then set pos as the tag for delete_confirm in your showDeleteDialog method

```
private void showDeleteDialog(int pos) {
    dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext).create();
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.dialog_delete, null);
    delete_local = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.delete_local);
    delete_confirm = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.delete_confirm);
    delete_cancel = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.delete_cancel);
    delete_local.setOnClickListener(this);
    delete_confirm.setOnClickListener(this);
    delete_cancel.setOnClickListener(this);

    delete_confirm.setTag(pos);

    view.setMinimumWidth((int) (((Activity) mContext).getWindowManager()  
        .getDefaultDisplay().getWidth() * 0.8));
    dialog.setView(view);
    dialog.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);

    dialog.show();
}
```

Comment: Thank you!   Now it can get the position when i click the confirm button in the dialog, but  it still does not remove the item from the list ,what  shall I do?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your code tbh. You're only adding 2 values to your mChilds and I dont understand why you're using a hashmap. Surely it would be better to just use a data structure like in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366132/delete-group-in-expandable-list

Comment: I am a beginner in android, Some of the code is a reference from other's,Should the delete event be put in adapter or in ManageFragment ,Thanks!

Comment: Could you tell me a bit more about the code? Like have you logged this code? Do you know where it's failing? Are the onClick events even being called?

Comment: Thank you again! The code's  intent is that when i click the group,   it expands and shows the children view, there is a delete button in the child,when the button is clicked,there is a alert dialog poped up, and when u click the confirm button, the current group item should be removed , and yes the onClick event  in the adapter are all executed,  but except these code: `mGroups.remove((Integer)tag);
                                       mChilds.remove((Integer)tag);                                               this.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: Cool, and is there any error? Or is the tag being returned as null? Try removing this line `mChilds.remove((Integer)tag);`. The tag you're using here is the position of the item in mGroups, not mChilds.

Comment: there is no error and the tag is right , after i remove that,it is still not working,Thank u!